# Secure @font-face in the network developer tools

Tags: security, font-face

I have a website called themtyp.es, where curated typedesigner can upload their fonts. How do I secure those fonts? Most of them are buyable and I get asked a lot to secure it more.

I have no clue whatsoever to do this. Maybe with .htaccess? or in the FTP uploader? I use commander one to upload websites.

Please please help! I would be very grateful.

I found a website that does it: https://www.colophon-foundry.org/typefaces/
If I go to https://www.colophon-foundry.org/fonts/value/value-serif-bold.woff2 there is this message. How did they do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice solution.

put

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !:\/\/([^.]+\.|)yoururl.com
# RewriteRule \.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)$">
Header append Cache-Control "must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

into the .htacces and all nice.